# OrderSend color ignored

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

Does somebody know why the color arrow isnt get painted in the next order call?

`OrderSend(symbolName, lotsNumber, bid, slip, 0, takeProfit, coment, Red);`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check `MQL4` Syntax:

```
iORS = OrderSend( Symbol(),     // .SYM          
                  OP_SELL,      // .OP <------------------------- MISSING
                  dLots,        // .LT
                  Bid,          // .ENTRY
                  5,            // .SLIPPAGE
                  0,            // .SL
                  0,            // .TP
                  sSHORT,       // .COMMENT
                  2000,         // .MAGNUM <--------------------- Red
                  0,            // .EXPIRE
                  Red           // .CLR
                  );
```

### Test ( always ) Return Value:

```
if ( iORS == EMPTY ) {... /* HANDLE FAILED OrderSend() */ }
```

Comment: I miss 0 as magnum and 0 as expire, before the color argument. (The OP is missing in the copy paste, but I had it in my original code).